# jQuery slideToggle() not showing :before element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

If I use only css than it is showing .nav-main:before{} element but with jQuery it is not toggle that element and always kept hidden.

***Note: This is happening on mobile (tested in Android Chrome)***

**jQuery**

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-main').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

**SCSS**

```
.nav-main{    

    @include breakpoint(max-desktop){
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 30%;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        z-index: 9999;
        padding:1px;
        background-color: $peter-river;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

        &:before{
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px;            
            top: -13px;
            content: "";
            display: block;
            width: 0; 
            height: 0; 
            border-left: 13px solid transparent;
            border-right: 13px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 13px solid $peter-river;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the 'current' class anywhere in your css.

Comment: That is for the `.menu-toggle` element and nothing to do with the `.nav-main:before` I think.!

Comment: You say "it is not toggle that element", which I don't understand, but what's being toggled in your JS is the 'current' class. So maybe your CSS should apply to `.current` instead of `.nav-main`?

Comment: `Note: This is happening on mobile (tested in Android Chrome)` Does it mean it work e.g on desktop browser?

Comment: If you see in `SCSS` there is a `:before` content (generating little triangle). So when I use jQuery to toggle my `.nav-main` element it is working but not showing `.nav-main:before` content (the little triangle)

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, that's right. On desktop it is working but on mobile it is not showing `:before` content

Comment: And if you don't toggle content and just set by default `.nav-main` visible, is the pseudo element `:before` shown on android mobile as it should?

Comment: @A.Wolff if I use only css for `.nav-main:before` and do not use jQuery than it is showing (just like as a visible block). This issue only happen when I use jQuery to toggle on click. Did you mean by that?

Comment: @JatinSoni That was exactly my question, thx for clarify it. Then this question would deserve more upvotes imho. Unfortunately, i couldn't help you on this one, could be a bug in your android browser version

Comment: I am using Android 4.1.2 with latest updated Chrome. This is happening  on multiple devices. I have checked on Samsung Galaxy and iBall tablet. Both has the same issue. Could you please suggest me anything where i can look for the solution?

Comment: @A.Wolff I have checked with other browsers like Maxthon, Opera but getting the same issue.

Comment: Please post ur entire menu code with html

Comment: Can you please post your entire code? better, if possible, add a jsfiddle demo as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your `:before` element is outside the bounds of the `.nav-main` element which can be seen by the fact that the `top` property is set to `-13px`.

jQuery `slideToggle()` sets `overflow:hidden` so this will hide anything that's outside the bounds of the box.

A solution (hacky) would be to set `overflow:visible!important` on the `.nav-main` in CSS or to run a callback function in the jQuery that set's overflow visible via the `css()` method:

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-main').slideToggle(100, function(){
         $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```